# How to read a column in a tab-delimited Excel file in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, console-application

I have some data of an excel file below. At first, I figured that reading from the file could be done using the Excel Library then using an OLEDB connection.   I managed to get the DocumentNo column data with the OLEDB approach. However, when the excel file is closed, I am unable to do the operation because it gives an error that "External table is not in the expected format." How can I read from the file even if it is closed?

```
10/4/2010                                                                            Paid Documents for Document Tracking - Customer                                                                        1

Paid Documents for Document Tracking - Customer                                                                                     



    CoCd    Customer    Trans.type  SG  Clearing    Clrng doc.  Assignment  Year    DocumentNo  Pstng Date  Doc. Date   Entry Dte   Crcy

    PLDT    5000007     4           4   1/15/2010   25003413    5000007     2010    408000139   1/7/2010    1/5/2010    1/12/2010   PHP
    PLDT    5000007     4           4   1/15/2010   25003634    5000007     2010    408000068   1/5/2010    12/22/2009  1/10/2010   PHP
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) for projects similiar to this with good success.

Have a look at their "quick start delimited" tutorial.

Based on your sample data above you'll need to use the "[IgnoreFirst(7)]" attribute on your row class because you've got some header information up there.  (7 is a guess)

Comment: Hi Brook, I can't seem to make this work. It always throws an error: -  err {"Line: 8 Column: 123. Empty value found for the Field: 'Customer' Class: 'DocumentRecord'. You must use the FieldNullValue attribute because this is a ValueType and can´t be null or you can use the Nullable Types feature of the .NET framework."} System.Exception {FileHelpers.BadUsageException}

Comment: Can you post your code for "DocumentRecord"?  It sounds like you need to either change [IgnoreFirst(7)] to [IgnoreFirst(8)], or if the field is nullable then make it nullable in the class.  Post your code and we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I've found NPOI, an open source port of a java library for Excel automation to be lightweight, fast and reliable.  It can be found here http://npoi.codeplex.com/.